# How to reduce the execusion time for the following code?

Tags: java, arrays

This is to develop a game.You're standing at index 0 of an n-element array named game . From some index (where 0<=i

1. Move Backward: If cell i-1 exists and contains a 0 , you can walk back to cell i-1.

   2. Move Forward:If cell i+1 contains a zero, you can walk to cell i+1.
      . If cell i+leap contains a zero, you can jump to cell i+leap.

If you're standing in cell n-1 or the value of i+leap>=n, you can walk or jump off the end of the array and win the game.

In other words, you can move from index i to index i-1,i+1 or i+leap  as long as the destination index is a cell containing a 0. If the destination index is greater than n-1, you win the game.

the code I thought of:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      int q=in.nextInt();
      int n,leap,move,prevmove,win;
      int game[];

      for(int i=1;i<=q;i++)
      {
          n=in.nextInt();
          leap=in.nextInt();
          move=0;
          prevmove=0;
          win=-1;
        game=new int[n];
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
           game[j]=in.nextInt();
      }


     while(win<0) {

            try{
                if(game[move+leap]==0)
                {
                    prevmove=move;
                    move=move+leap;
                    continue;
                }
               }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               win=1;
               continue;
           }

          try{

                if(game[move+1]==0)
                {
                    prevmove=move;
                    move=move+1;
                    continue;
                }
               }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               win=1;
               continue;
           }

          try{

                if(game[move-1]==0)
                {
                    if(prevmove!=move-1){
                    prevmove=move;
                    move=move+leap;
                    continue;}
                    else 
                    {
                    win=0;
                    continue;
                    }

                }
               }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               win=0;
               continue;
           }



          win=0;

          }


       if(win==0)
      System.out.println("NO");
      else
      System.out.println("YES");





      }

in.close();
}
}
```

Comment: You can try to improve this code, by may be checking size and not relying on OutOfBoundException to tell you the edge, that should save you some time.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are having an issue with / what isn't working?

Comment: The program doesn't execute within the given time limit. I would like to have  alterations to my code so that the time of execution reduces.